# What exactly happens to the object reference variable in a stack frame when its assigned a new value?

Tags: java, memory-management

I believe this is a simple question, but I haven't been able to find a straight answer. What happens to the reference variable in the stack if you replace it with a new instance in the same method?

In other words,
Say you have a program that does  this:

```
...void main(...){
someClass x = new someClass(false);
x.doSomething();
x = new someClass(true);
x.doSomething();
}
```

I understand that an object reference variable is placed in the stack frame which points to the object in heap (please correct me if I'm wrong). When I replace x with a new instance of someClass(), does the existing reference value of the object reference variable in the stack change to point to the new object, or is the old reference variable in the stack frame dropped and replaced with a new object reference variable pointing to the new object? Are reference variables mutable? Does this all happen in the same stack frame, or does something else happen?

[image](https://i.ibb.co/108WywS/drawing.png)

Comment: *does the existing reference value of the object reference variable in the stack change to point to the new object, or is the old reference variable in the stack frame dropped and replaced with a new object reference variable pointing to the new object* The difference in your mental model between these is unclear. Have you tried drawing a stack frame?

Comment: _Are reference variables mutable?_ You **can** create immutable (reference) variables (and fields) by declaring them as final: `final someClass x = new someClass(false); final int maxSize = 15;`. If you do this you cannot later reassign a new value (i.e. `x = new someClass(true);` no longer compiles). If you don't declare them as final they are mutable and you can assign a new value to it.

Comment: I've made an image trying to show what I'm thinking: https://i.ibb.co/108WywS/drawing.png Please let me know if it makes sense.

Comment: For me this whole concept of "drop and replace a reference variable" doesn't make sense. How should the JVM implement it? By incrementing and then decrementing the stack pointer? But what if the reference variable is not at the top of the stack but rather in a sandwich position between other variables?

Comment: The reference variable occupies a position in memory. When it is reassigned, the contents of that memory location change. 'Drop and replace' has no meaning here.

Comment: thank you user207421, that's all I wanted to know.

Comment: Note that for this behaviour there is no difference between reference variables (like your `SomeClass x` and a primitive local variable (like `int x`). Both just hold a value and when you re-assign them they will hold a different value. One of the values just happens to be a reference to an object and the other is a number.

Answer (score 0):

Let's analyse the code in sequence:

- `someClass x = new someClass(false);` : `x` holds a reference to a newly allocated object of class `someClass`.
- `x.doSomething();` : the `doSomething()` method is called with object `x` as the `this` object. If the method stores `this` into another object, it will be referenced more than once.
- `x = new someClass(true);` : `x` now holds a reference to another newly allocated object of class `someClass`. The previous object is no longer referenced by `x`, so it may be reclaimed by the garbage collector at some point, unless a reference has been stored elsewhere by the `doSomething()` method or possibly by the constructor.